# Network with bridge and port forwarding?

Tags: networking

Below is my current (and planned) home network configuration. I would like to connect my non-wifi-capable desktop to my home network. The question is: **HOW**?

[image]

- What device do I need?

The primary requirement is that I need to be able to forward ports to my desktop.

- How would I achieve this?
- Is there something like "double port forwarding"?

Could anyone please explain this configuration to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get ethernet client bridges, such as the old Linksys WET11. As these have gone away a more practical idea is to buy an "access point" (*not* a router) and set it to client mode. Then it's just as though it were a (slow) ethernet cable, so there's only the port forwarding on the Tomato router.

An even better idea, as stated by Dmitry Trukhanov is to use a USB or PCI wifi adaptor, you say IIS so that indicates Windows, and unless you're talking NT4 (in which case *upgrade*) Windows certainly has wifi support.

Are you simply out of cable range for wire, per your diagram you should still have four fixed ethernet ports spare.

Comment: The problem is that I've Windows 7 Ultimate x64 and I can't get any drivers for my PENTAGRAM horNET Wi-Fi PCI [P 6121-L6] : RTL8185L that would actually work (I've spent too many hours on that). So now I'm using old laptop with Kerio WinRoute which bridges WiFi and my desktop, but I have to subnets 192.168.1.xxx wifi and 192.168.2.xxx behind Kerio WinRoute -- that's temporary -- I need to eliminate this laptop and get some kind of device that would do the same and wil ALLOW me to forward ports. Would ASUS WL-330GE be a good choice? Is it transparent so that port fwd occurs only on main router?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the firmware replacement distros for WRT54 can be used as a repeater/bridge. I have a Linksys WRT54GS on which I installed DD-WRT. From some instructions found on the net, I made it an access point, so it connects to the wireless network, and then provides an ethernet connection to whichever device I want to connect. I used the instructions here:

```
  http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge
```

Worked fine for me, and solved a problem where I had a wifi-only location but had to connect multiple computers, some of which did not have wireless connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your desktop to one of the ethernet ports on the router and set up port forwarding in the router. You can port forward different ports (IIS, FTP, etc) to the desktop while still port forwarding the Starcraft ports to the laptop.

Comment: The thing is that I'm not able to connect with wire to my router - I need to have this device under question mark.

Answer (score 0):

You need simple WiFi network card. In my organization I use D-Link network cards, both USB and PCI form. All you need to do is set up it as regular notebook wifi card. And what do you mean under "double port forwarding".

Comment: This desktop is not WiFi-capable. The only way I can connect it is through ethernet.